# woff and ttf fonts 404 not found

Tags: css, fonts, sass, webpack, font-face

I'm using webpack to compile my sass files.
I have a `font-face` that looks like this:

```
@font-face 
    font-family: "Alef"
    src: url("..\..\public\fonts\Alef\Alef-Webfont\Alef-Bold.eot")
    src: url("..\..\public\fonts\Alef\Alef-Webfont\Alef-Bold.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("..\..\public\fonts\Alef\Alef-Webfont\Alef-Bold.woff") format("woff"), url("..\..\public\fonts\Alef\Alef-Webfont\Alef-Bold.ttf") format("truetype"), url("..\..\public\fonts\Alef\Alef-Webfont\Alef-Bold.svg#alefbold") format("svg")
    font-weight: bold
    font-style: normal
```

and this is how the loaders in my webpack config file looks like

```
{
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
                loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.sass$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'raw-loader!sass-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: 'raw'
            }
```

but, i'm getting 404 on the ttf and woff, so this font appears only in chrome (doesn't appear in firefox and edge)

thanks!

Comment: I don't have the problem when I'm disabling JS, in my app it happens all the time (eve'n with js). It seems like a problem in webpack

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solved! I separated the `srcs`, like that:

```
@font-face 
    font-family: "Alef"
    src: url("..\..\public\fonts\Alef\Alef-Webfont\Alef-Bold.eot")
    src: url("..\..\public\fonts\Alef\Alef-Webfont\Alef-Bold.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype")
    src: url("..\..\public\fonts\Alef\Alef-Webfont\Alef-Bold.woff") format("woff")
    src: url("..\..\public\fonts\Alef\Alef-Webfont\Alef-Bold.ttf") format("truetype")
    src: url("..\..\public\fonts\Alef\Alef-Webfont\Alef-Bold.svg#alefbold") format("svg")
    font-weight: bold
    font-style: normal
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution helped me as well. Good job

Comment: Thanks! Spent ages trying to fix my errors in the console.

Comment: I did not work for me. I am posting my query with screenshot below. Please help me.