# TypeScript cannot resolve Font file

Tags: typescript, webpack

I've been trying for a while to import a font in TypeScript and I cant figure out what I am doing wrong. Ive been looking over a few related questions but the solutions dont seem to be working for me.

my file directory structure is as such:

```
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── logo.png
│   │   └── menu_background.jpg
│   ├── fonts
│   │   └── Pixel-Noir.ttf
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.ts
│   ├── menu.scene.ts
│   └── styles
│       └── fonts.scss
├── tsconfig.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

In webpack:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      ...
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
```

In fonts.scss:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'game-font';
  src: url('../fonts/Pixel-Noir.tff') format('truetype');
}
```

in custom.d.ts:

```
declare module '*.ttf';
```

When I run my dev server, I dont get any errors, although the Intellisense in IntelliJ is saying `Cannot resolve file 'Pixel-Noir.tff` in my fonts.scss file which seems to be the problem. The project loads and I dont get any errors in the console, it just doesnt load the font.

I appreciate any help, let me know if there is more information needed.

Edit:
It was suggested that this may be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897205/woff-and-ttf-fonts-404-not-found) but the solution for that question was to separate out the different source files in the font-face definition. I only have one source file, so its as separated as it can be. The file loaders are also different in his webpack config. I can try to use them but I have a feeling it may be out of date as that question is three years old now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [woff and ttf fonts 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897205/woff-and-ttf-fonts-404-not-found)

Comment: thanks for the link @Adriano, that question may be helpful but it looks like the solution was to separate out the srcs. I only have a .tff file, and I think the problem is that it cant find it on the path.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the answer was to change the module type def in `custom.d.ts` to:

```
declare module "*.woff2" {
  const value: any;
  export = value;
}
```

I'd imagine that the same would apply if you're using `*.ttf` instead.